# Recursive assembly code stack pointer issues. (mips)

Tags: recursion, assembly, stack, mips

```
def count_partitions(n, m):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n < 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        l = count_partitions(n, m-1) + count_partitions(n-m, m)
        return l
```

Trying to convert this python code into MIPS assembly. My assembly code does its job but after it gets to the right answer, it continues and gets to absurd numbers.

I tried debugging with mars.jar and found out that my stack pointer didnt get updated at one point. Thanks a lot.

My code:

```
    .data

    prompt1: .asciiz  "\Enter an integer to partition (n): "
    prompt2: .asciiz  "\Enter an integer for size of the partition (m): "
    default: .asciiz "\nstuff "

   .text

    main:
      la $a0,  prompt1          
      li $v0,4
      syscall              

      li $v0, 5
      syscall       
      move $t0, $v0 # $t0 = n

      la $a0,  prompt2          
      li $v0,4
      syscall              

      li $v0, 5
      syscall       
      move $t1, $v0 # $t1 = m

      add $a0, $t0, $zero
      add $a1, $t1, $zero

      addi $sp,$sp,-4
      sw $ra,0($sp)

      jal count_partitions

      lw $ra,0($sp)
      addi $sp,$sp,4

      move $a0,$v0        
      li $v0, 1
      syscall                #prints the default

      li $v0, 10
      syscall

count_partitions:

    addi $sp,$sp,-16

    sw $s1,12($sp)
    sw $a1,8($sp)
    sw $a0,4($sp)
    sw $ra,0($sp)

    bne $a0,$zero,case1

    addi $v0,$v0,1
    j return

   case1:

    slti $t0,$a0,0
    beq  $t0,$zero,case2

    j return

   case2:

    bne $a1,$zero,case3

    j return

   case3:

    addi $a1,$a1,-1
    jal  count_partitions

    addi $t7,$zero,1
    mult $v0,$t7
    mflo $s1

    addi $a1,$a1,1
    sub  $a0,$a0,$a1
    jal  count_partitions

    addi $t7,$zero,1
    mult $v0,$t7
    mflo $t2

    add $v0,$s1,$t2            

  return:

        lw $ra,0($sp)
        lw $a0,4($sp)
        lw $a1,8($sp)
        lw $s1,12($sp)
        addi $sp,$sp,16


      jr $ra
```

Comment: At what point did your stack pointer not get updated?

Comment: Actually the issue is probably a0 getting updated rather than not getting updated. when i get the answer right on v0, a0 is 0 and a1 is 1.

but after that i expect a0 to stay 0 but it gets updated to 1 so the flow continues.

Comment: The error is at this point:

http://i.imgur.com/5Bw8NP1.png